# What's the best way modularise PHPUnit Selenium2 tests?

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver

I'm using the [Selenium2TestCase](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium/blob/master/Tests/Selenium2TestCaseTest.php) object to run some tests on a site. I'm trying to modularise these tests for ease of writing and new tests and readability.

With my limited knowledge of Selenium WD and PHPUnit and a distinct lack of useful information available online, I've jumped in and start by splitting my tests up into separate 'page' objects. I don't know whether this is the best solution or if its even technically possible.

This is a simplified version of what I have at the moment...

```
class Selenium2TestCase_Extension extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase
{
    public function testPages(){

        $pages = array('about', 'contact');

        foreach($pages as $page){

            // Can I instantiate and run the tests in About_Test from here???
        }
    }
}

class About_Test extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase 
{
    public function testTitle(){
        $this->url('/about');

        $this->assertEquals("About Us", $this->title());
    }

}

class Home_Test extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase
{
    public function testTitle(){
        $this->url('/home');

        $this->assertEquals("Welcome", $this->title());
    }

}
```

I'm not sure if I'm attempting the impossible here or what so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: It seems like you're basically trying to re-invent the wheel; there already are some options for, well, organizing your tests:
- by their location on your filesystem
- using testsuites which you configure in xml
- using the \@group/\@author annotation or the \@small, \@medium, \@large annotations
(SO didn't allow me to post those annotations without escaping them, disregard the backslashes)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can it with `exec` or `system`, or something similar. But it seems that is not proper way.

Is it [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

You could

1. use [groups](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration.groups) for launching some of tests.
2. store those tests in one separate folder and run test over it using [command-line interface](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/textui.html#textui.clioptions).
3. run only wanted tests using [command-line interface](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/textui.html#textui.clioptions).
4. (in your case) use [data provider](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.data-providers) and write one test only.

Comment: Thank you for this. I think you're correct but I'm new to both Selenium and PHPUnit so I'm having trouble finding any info on this.